# Cannot enter unicode text in Android

Tags: android, xml, unicode, utf-8

I need to enter the text in unicode directly from the keyboard (Vietnamese for this time) but nothing happens. It once works with another simple app but I don't know what am I missing so this app won't allow unicode input.

I've tried

> Properties the project -> Resource -> Text file encoding -> Other -> UTF-8

or `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in every xml activity or even in AndroidManifest.xml but no luck.

Is there anything I missed? Most of the tutorials I found are listed above.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you changed the file encoding in the Settings of Android Studio ?

Comment: Sorry not to mention, I use Eclipse.

Comment: Did you tried with Android Studio ? Aha Eclipse is no longer used to develop on Android :P

Comment: Sadly I'm used to Eclipse, tried with Android Studio but can't event find the activity declaration in the manifest haha

Answer (score 0):

Project properties only configures new files.

Edit the properties for **each file** and change the encoding to "UTF-8".